# Java reflection with a java Process

Tags: java, reflection, bungeecord

I have a [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) which is a Java application which was created from ProcessBuilder by running a command like `java -Xms1024M -jar my.jar`. This works fantastically, but the application I started does not use `System.in` for its input, so I can NOT use `process.getOutputStream()`.

How could I get an instance of the running application from the process to use Java Reflection to send input?  If I can't, how would I go about using Java Reflection to start the application from my runnable, then use Java reflection to get something I can work with.

To be more specific, I am trying to do this for [BungeeCord](https://github.com/SpigotMC/BungeeCord).

- The main class is `net.md_5.bungee.Bootstrap`.
- Bootstrap calls the static method `main` in `net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCordLauncher`.
- BungeeCordLauncher creates an instance of `net.md_5.bungee` and puts this instance in a static field called `instance` in `net.md_5.bungee.api.ProxyServer` AND there is a get method (Maybe this could be used for java reflection?)
- Inside `BungeeCord.class` there is a method called `getConsoleReader()` and this is what I ultimately need to get and I need the current instance of it for this specific process.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Rather then using `Process`, use a custom classloader (like `URLClassloader`) and load the application through it, then you will have access to the class information

Comment: How *does* the application get its input? Surely it wasn't designed to acquire its input via Reflection?

Comment: @EJP It gets its input from 'FileDescriptor.in'.